Jmeter Split data between different thread based on Index number
I need to configure Jmeter in a way that each thread takes a specific index of data only ...like first thread takes first 200 set of data, second thread takes second 200 set of data ,third takes third 200 set of data like wise. How do i do that ?
I need to configure Jmeter in a way that each thread takes a specific index of data only ...like first thread takes first 200 set of data, second thread takes second 200 set of data ,third takes third 200 set of data like wise.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The easiest is going for Extended CSV Data Set Config plugin which can allocate blocks of values to different virtual users.

The plugin can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager
Otherwise you can put the values into different CSV files and read them with __CSVRead() and __threadNum() functions combination.
